# How to compile OpenCV 3.2.0 with Python on OSX?

Tags: python, makefile, cmake, opencv

I'm currently on OSX 10.11.5 and I'm trying to build OpenCV 3.2.0 with Python, but even by disabling as many options as possible I can't seem to convince cmake to generate makefiles with `BUILD_opencv_python ON`.

Here's full cmake output:

```
-- FP16: Feature disabled
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.4" (found /usr/local/bin/python3)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.2" (found /usr/local/bin/python3)
-- Found apache ant 1.9.7: /usr/local/ant/bin/ant
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2017-06-27T16:16:09Z
--     Host:                        Darwin 15.5.0 x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.8.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
--     C++ Compiler:                /Applications/IDEsAndEditors/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.0.0.7000072)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-sse2 -mno-avx -mno-sse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-sse2 -mno-avx -mno-sse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /Applications/IDEsAndEditors/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-sse2 -mno-avx -mno-sse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-sse2 -mno-avx -mno-sse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/libz.dylib -framework Cocoa stdc++
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core imgproc imgcodecs highgui
--     Disabled:                    calib3d features2d flann java ml objdetect photo shape stitching superres video videoio videostab world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python2 python3 ts viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     Cocoa:                       YES
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/libz.dylib (ver 1.2.5)
--     JPEG:                        NO
--     WEBP:                        NO
--     PNG:                         NO
--     TIFF:                        NO
--     JPEG 2000:                   NO
--     OpenEXR:                     NO
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                YES (ver 3.5.0)
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     AVFoundation:                NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/NO
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            GCD
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  NO
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.13)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/local/ant/bin/ant (ver 1.9.7)
--     JNI:                         /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       NO
--     Performance tests:           NO
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/cv/opencv-3.2.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/cv/opencv-3.2.0/build
```

I don't understand why python2 is disabled as unavailable.

What's the recommended OSX setup to enable OpenCV's Python bindings ?

Comment: Not sure what's going on - I build **OpenCV** from source on my Mac and I get loads of **CPU/HW Features** listing all the SSE2/SSE3/SSE4/AVX features after the `Configuration: Release` line you have when I run `opencv_version -v`. Have you `git pulled` from GitHub lately?

Comment: Your listing also seems to show a Python 2 Interpreter at version 2.7.13.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have disabled as many flags as possible in attempting to enable `BUILD_opencv_python` to cooperate...think I might've gone too far :) I did `git pull` recently and have tried 3 different routes: 1. downloading the zipped source from opencv.org (guessing always a bit behind but more stable), 2. pulling from the [opencv repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv), 3. pulling from the [Itseez repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv). Neither options made a difference :( What else can I try ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's much simpler to install OpenCV Python bindings via pip:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Currently this installed opencv 3.4.3:

```
python -c 'import cv2;print(cv2.__version__)'
3.4.3
```

And webcam/windowing also worked which previously was problematic (probably related to homebrew Python installs vs OSX Python Framwork install, existing Qt versions installed on the system, etc.)